# There is Already Entity Type Shape for Entity Error When updating model from data base

Tags: entity-framework, model, entity

I got this error when updating model from database in edmx file

There is already Entity Type Shape for entity

I chose my table and click on finish and got this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is still interested... it's because you have already added that entity and have deleted it and for some reason it has not been removed in some of the model definition files... most likely in the [model_name].edmx.diagram  file... you can manually remove it  or restore the files